# Programmatically check if current page is personalised and get ID

Tags: personalization

I have a 2 components in my webpage running personalisation rule.

- Component A: 1 Rule + 1 Default Rule
- Component B: 2 Rule + 1 Default Rule

I want to be able to check if there a personalisation rule other than the default rule was applied, and print out some form of an ID. This ID data will be fed to an external analytics system.

Is there some way to determine if the current page has any any personalisation rule applied and get the corresponding ID?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's going to be a good idea or not to do this (performance implications), but if you wanted to have a look at something like this, you might find what you need...??

if you have a Sitecore Item, you can call the following extension method like so:

```
var renderings = item.GetRenderingReferences("default");

foreach (var rendering in renderings)
{ 
  //access rendering.Settings.Blah here
}

//extension to add to your solution
public static class RenderingExtensions
{
    public static Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] GetRenderingReferences(this Item item, string deviceName)
    {
        LayoutField layoutField = item.Fields["__final renderings"];
        if (layoutField == null)
            return null;
        Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = null;
        if (item.Database != null)
        {
            renderings = layoutField.GetReferences(item.Database.GetDeviceItem(deviceName));
        }
        else
        {
            renderings = layoutField.GetReferences(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetDeviceItem(deviceName));
        }
        return renderings;
    }

    public static DeviceItem GetDeviceItem(this Database db, string deviceName)
    {
        return db.Resources.Devices.GetAll().Where(d => d.Name.ToLower() == deviceName.ToLower()).First();
    }
}
```

[image]